# Python Flow control and ifs

Tags: python, python-2.7

Q1. I want to modify below code so that the evens list contains only the even numbers of the numbers list. We don't need to print anything.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
evens =[]
for number in numbers:
    evens.append(number)
```

Q2.Add a clause to the if statement such that if the user's input is "q", your program prints "Quit"

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
evens = []
running = True
while running:
    evens = [n for n in numbers if n%2==0]
    numbers = []
    print("Evens:", evens)
    
    text = raw_input("Add a number (q to quit): ")
    try:
        if text == "q":
            running = False
        else:
            numbers.append(int(text))
     except:
         print("Please input a valid number.")
```

It might seem long, but I wanted to have the 100% functionality you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, @Btables EDIT: Hopefully this works now